# Writing a list of books in the statement of purpose

Tags: lists

I'm currently writing a statement of purpose for graduate school application. I would like to know the best way to present the list of books that I have independently studied.

I wrote the following paragraph:

> I taught myself mathematics by studying some textbooks in depth. I would like to mention a few: 1) Hatcher's, May's, and Spanier's Algebraic topology" 2) Griffiths', and Fulton's books on Algebraic geometry

Every item in that list corresponds to the books that I have studied in a certain subject.

I would like to know if this is a good way to present it.

Thanks

Comment: Is that three books or five?

Comment: Five books. I wrote an apostrophe after each author's name to indicate that they are not co-authors of the same book. The numbering is related to the subject

Comment: But they all appear to have the same subject, algebraic topology.

Comment: Oops. I meant to write algebraic geometry in item number 2.

Comment: I'd use just the names: *... in depth, in particular the books on algebraic topology by Hatcher, May and Spanier and those on algebraic geometry by Griffiths and Fulton.*

Comment: Also, in the same paragraph, can I write: I also studied the following computer science books: Cormen's algorithms, Korth's "Databases", and so on ?

Comment: Sure. But why "the following"? That's wholly redundant with the colon.

Comment: "I taught myself Algebraic Topology by studying in depth the texts by Hatcher, May and Spanier, and Algebraic Geometry by studying Griffiths and Fulton."

Answer (score 1):

Be brief and concise.  You don't have to say "in depth," since that's assumed.  The best wording is actually what you used in the question, then a bullet list with author names and book titles.  If titles are self-explanatory, then no need to append field (don't capitalize).

My independent study has included:

- Hatcher, [Book title] (algebraic topology)
- May, [Book title] (algebraic topology)
- Spanier, [Book title] (algebraic topology)
- Griffith, [Book title] (algebraic geometry)
- Fulton, [Book title} (algebraic geometry)